# Is there a way to call useContext in a click callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning React and have a custom Context accessible with a use method:

```js
// In a Provider file.
export const useUsefulObject(): UsefulObject {
  return useContext(...)
}
```

I want to use UsefulObject in a click callback in another file. For convenience, I have that callback wrapped in a method `someLogic`.

```js
const PageComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return <Button onClick={(e) => someLogic(e)} />;
}

function someLogic(e: Event) { 
  const usefulObject = useUsefulObject();
  usefulObject.foo(e, ...); 
}
```

However, VS Code alerts that calling useUsefulObject in someLogic is a violation of the rules of hooks since it's called outside of a component method.

I can pass the object down (the below code works!) but it feels like it defeats the point of Contexts to avoid all the passing down. Is there a better way than this?

```js
const PageComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const usefulObject = useUsefulObject();
  return <Button onClick={(e) => someLogic(e, usefulObject)} />;
}

function someLogic(e: Event, usefulObject) { 
  usefulObject.foo(e, ...); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hooks need to be called while the component is rendering, so your last idea is one of the possible ways to do so. Another option is you can create a custom hook which accesses the context and creates the someLogic function:

```
const PageComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const someLogic = useSomeLogic();
  return <Button onClick={(e) => someLogic(e)} />
}

function useSomeLogic() {
  const usefulObject = useUsefulObject();
  const someLogic = useCallback((e: Event) => {
    usefulObject.foo(e, ...);
  }, [usefulObject]);
  return someLogic;
}
```

Comment: Piggybacking off this good answer, I would suggest that OP read the Rules of Hooks [from the horses' mouth](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).